# Slow Like Query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have 20 million Record in table its Schema is like below

```
FieldName   Datatype
id          bigint(Auto Inc,Primarykey)
name        varchar(255)
phone       varchar(255)
deleted_at  timestamp
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
```

It has index on name and phone column

```
Column  Index type
name    GIN trgm index
phone   btree index, GIN trgm index
```

Created index using the following commands

```
CREATE INDEX btree_idx ON contacts USING btree (phone);
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON contacts USING GIN (phone gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_name ON contacts USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

I am running the below query

```
select * from contacts where phone like '%6666666%' limit 15;
```

I am doing contains query on phone. The above query takes more than 5 min to get a result. Let me provide the explain statement of this.

```
explain  analyse select * from contacts where phone like '%6666666%' limit 15;
```

```
Limit  (cost=1774.88..1830.57 rows=15 width=65) (actual time=7970.553..203001.985 rows=15 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on contacts  (cost=1774.88..10819.13 rows=2436 width=65) (actual time=7970.552..203001.967 rows=15 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((phone)::text ~~ '%6666666%'::text)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 254869
        Heap Blocks: lossy=2819
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..1774.27 rows=2436 width=0) (actual time=6720.978..6720.978 rows=306226 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((phone)::text ~~ '%6666666%'::text)
Planning Time: 0.139 ms
Execution Time: 203002.791 ms
```

Here what can I do to optimize my query? and bring the result under 5 sec would be optimal

Comment: Try running an `analyze` on the table to ensure the statistics are up to date. How are the phone numbers stored? If they're normalized, a `like` may be unnecessary.

Comment: Added analyze query in the question and phone number are stored directly in the table so like query is required to get the result. User will type minimum 7 number and I have to show the number which contains user input number @Schwern

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done as you suggested added text format of the query.

Comment: The estimates are quite off in the plan. Does running `analyze contacts;` or `vacuum analyze contacts;` change anything? Nearly 7 seconds to retrieve only 300000 rows from the index seems rather slow as well. What kind of harddisk does your server have?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using AWS RDS with 20GB General Purpose (SSD),2GB ram and 2vCPU. instance type is t3.small and postgresql version is 12.3.

Comment: Could it be that these are artificial data with `666` occurring very often.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no. I was testing against my query for some number in give me result in half seconds. So i was happy with the query and made the project live and when real user were using there were many timeout. So i triend with 10 to 100 of sets of number and check what is happening and then i found 666666 was giving worst output.

Comment: That is unsurprising, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cause of the bad performance is probably

```
Heap Blocks: lossy=2819
```

Your `work_mem` setting is to small to contain a bitmap with one bit per table row, so PostgreSQL degrades it to one bit per 8kB block. This leads to many more rechecks than necessary.

Also, your test is bad. The search string contains only the trigram `666`, which will match many rows that don't satisfy the query and have to be removed during recheck. A trigram index is not effective in this pathological case. Test with a number that contains more digits.

Comment: Current work_mem was 4MB I increased in to 16MB and then i perform below query


explain  (analyse,VERBOSE ) select * from contacts where  phone like '%6666667%' limit 15;


and it output is below

Comment: Limit  (cost=578.90..634.59 rows=15 width=65) (actual time=232.579..57587.617 rows=15 loops=1)  Output: id, name, phone, deleted_at, created_at, updated_at   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.contacts  (cost=578.90..9630.62 rows=2438 width=65) (actual time=232.577..57587.599 rows=15 loops=1)         Recheck Cond: ((contacts.phone)::text ~~ '%6666667%'::text)         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3402         Heap Blocks: exact=3231         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..578.29 rows=2438 width=0) (actual time=227.403..227.403 rows=29417 loops=1)

Comment: Index Cond: ((contacts.phone)::text ~~ '%6666667%'::text)Planning Time: 0.097 msExecution Time: 57587.660 ms

Comment: The performance improved from 75 seconds to 55 seconds. i want to make it under 5 seconds

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I got your point that for same digit it will not work. I have one more field where is search which is name in which arabic character are store and for that i have created another query can you checkout for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644778/slow-like-query-in-postgres-with-unicode-string